# R data.table: row-based conditions split/apply/combine

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`

```
initial.date <- as.POSIXct('2018-10-27 10:00:00',tz='GMT')
last.date <- as.POSIXct('2018-12-28 17:00:00',tz='GMT') 
    PriorityDateTime=seq.POSIXt(from=initial.date,to = last.date,by = '30 sec')
    TradePrice=seq(from=1, to=length(PriorityDateTime),by = 1)
    ndf<- data.frame(PriorityDateTime,TradePrice)
    ndf$InstrumentSymbol <- rep_len(x = c('asset1','asset2'),length.out = length(ndf$PriorityDateTime))
    ndf$id <- seq(1:length(x = ndf$InstrumentSymbol))
    ndf$datetime <- ymd_hms(ndf$PriorityDateTime)
    res <- ndf %>% data.table()
```

Looking like this:

```
    > res
         PriorityDateTime TradePrice InstrumentSymbol   id            datetime
   1: 2018-10-27 10:00:00          1           asset1    1 2018-10-27 10:00:00
   2: 2018-10-27 10:00:30          2           asset2    2 2018-10-27 10:00:30
   3: 2018-10-27 10:01:00          3           asset1    3 2018-10-27 10:01:00
   4: 2018-10-27 10:01:30          4           asset2    4 2018-10-27 10:01:30
   5: 2018-10-27 10:02:00          5           asset1    5 2018-10-27 10:02:00
```

Using `data.table` what is the most elegant and fast way to:

1. Split: **For each line** define the other lines that have a `datetime` at most 60 secs in the past or future (time difference less than 60secs), and have the same `InstrumentSymbol` as this line's.
2. Apply: among these close lines, which one has the closest `TradePrice` to this line's `TradePrice[i]`: get the `index` in the original `data.frame` and the `TradePrice` of this other row
3. Combine: recombine the results as new columns into the original `data.table` for example as new columns `index.minpricewithin60` and `minpricewithin60`

Example result:

```
> res
         PriorityDateTime TradePrice InstrumentSymbol   id            datetime minpricewithin60 index.minpricewithin60
   1: 2018-10-27 10:00:00          1           asset1    1 2018-10-27 10:00:00                2                      2
   2: 2018-10-27 10:00:30          2           asset2    2 2018-10-27 10:00:30                4                      4
   3: 2018-10-27 10:01:00          3           asset1    3 2018-10-27 10:01:00                1                      1
   4: 2018-10-27 10:01:30          4           asset2    4 2018-10-27 10:01:30                2                      2
   5: 2018-10-27 10:02:00          5           asset1    5 2018-10-27 10:02:00                3                      3
```

In `base` I can fix a row ans use it for conditions. For example if I want to get the first `TradePrice` where `id` is the same as this row's `id`, I can do `apply(df,1, function(x) df$TradePrice[which(df$id==x["id"])[1]])`. Could you please explain how `data.table`'s joins (for example) can achieve the same?

EDIT: Data is now larger, any answer that I can run on my decent PC (i7 4750 2B, 12GB RAM) in less than 2.5mins will be considered. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP did not mention the size of the new dataset. But a `Rcpp` solution should speed things up.

As per previous comment:

```
mtd1 <- function() {
    ndf[, rn:=.I]
    iidx <- ndf[
        .(inst=InstrumentSymbol, prevMin=datetime-60L, nextMin=datetime+60L, idx=id, tp=TradePrice),

        .SD[id != idx, rn[which.min(abs(TradePrice - tp))]],

        by=.EACHI,

        on=.(InstrumentSymbol=inst, datetime>=prevMin, datetime<=nextMin)];

    ndf[, c("minpricewithin60", "index.minpricewithin60") := .SD[iidx$V1, .(TradePrice, id)]]
}
```

arg0naut's approach:

```
mtd2 <- function() {
    res2[, `:=` (min_60 = datetime - 60, plus_60 = datetime + 60, idx = .I)][
        res2,  on = .(InstrumentSymbol = InstrumentSymbol, datetime >= min_60, datetime <= plus_60), allow.cartesian = TRUE][
            idx != i.idx, .SD[which.min(abs(i.TradePrice - TradePrice))], by = id][
                , .(id, minpricewithin60 = i.TradePrice, index.minpricewithin60 = i.idx)][
                    res, on = .(id)][, `:=` (min_60 = NULL, plus_60 = NULL, idx = NULL)]

}
```

A possible Rcpp approach:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
NumericVector nearestPrice(NumericVector id, NumericVector datetime, NumericVector price) {
    int i, j, n = id.size();
    NumericVector res(n);
    double prev, diff;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        prev = 100000;

        j = i-1;
        while (datetime[j] >= datetime[i]-60 && j>=0) {
            diff = std::abs(price[i] - price[j]);

            if (diff < prev) {
                res[i] = id[j];
                prev = diff;
            }
            j--;
        }

        j = i+1;
        while (datetime[j] <= datetime[i]+60 && j<=n) {
            diff = std::abs(price[i] - price[j]);

            if (diff < prev) {
                res[i] = id[j];
                prev = diff;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }

    return(res);
}
')

mtd3 <- function() {
    setorder(ndf2, InstrumentSymbol, PriorityDateTime)
    iidx <- ndf2[, nearestPrice(.I, datetime, TradePrice), by=.(InstrumentSymbol)]
    ndf2[, c("minpricewithin60", "index.minpricewithin60") := .SD[iidx$V1, .(TradePrice, id)]]
}
```

timing code:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mtd1(), mtd2(), mtd3(), times=3L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
 mtd1() 49447.09713 49457.12408 49528.14395 49467.15103 49568.66737 49670.18371     3
 mtd2() 64189.67241 64343.67138 64656.40058 64497.67034 64889.76466 65281.85899     3
 mtd3()    17.33116    19.58716    22.36557    21.84316    24.88277    27.92238     3
```

data:

```
set.seed(0L)
initial.date <- as.POSIXct('2018-01-01 00:00:00', tz='GMT')
last.date <- initial.date + 30 * (180000/2)
PriorityDateTime <- seq.POSIXt(from=initial.date, to=last.date, by='30 sec')

library(data.table)
ndf <- data.table(PriorityDateTime=c(PriorityDateTime, PriorityDateTime),
    TradePrice=rnorm(length(PriorityDateTime)*2, 100, 20),
    InstrumentSymbol=rep(c('asset1','asset2'), each=length(PriorityDateTime)),
    datetime=c(PriorityDateTime, PriorityDateTime))
setorder(ndf, InstrumentSymbol, PriorityDateTime)[, id := .I]
res <- copy(ndf)
res2  <- copy(ndf)
ndf2 <- copy(ndf)
```

Comment: Many thanks for you answer, will try it out. As a side question do you know if some compiled c++ code could be included as well?

Comment: maybe u can post a question under Rcpp. the Rcpp experts should be able to answer you

Comment: Using the originql dataset, this doesn't return the right solution since this first line should be linked to the third index with price of 3. I guess this is just an error in the function? However the time savings are fantastic...

`> head(mtd3())
      PriorityDateTime TradePrice InstrumentSymbol id            datetime minpricewithin60 index.minpricewithin60
1: 2018-10-27 10:00:00          1           asset1  1 2018-10-27 10:00:00                5                      5`

Comment: @gpier my id happens to be the row number as well. Changing is to .I should work

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
res <- res[1:5,]

res2 <- setDT(res)
res2 <- res2[, `:=` (min_60 = datetime - 60, plus_60 = datetime + 60, idx = .I)][
res2,  on = .(InstrumentSymbol = InstrumentSymbol, datetime >= min_60, datetime <= plus_60), allow.cartesian = TRUE][
idx != i.idx, .SD[which.min(abs(i.TradePrice - TradePrice))], by = id][
, .(id, minpricewithin60 = i.TradePrice, index.minpricewithin60 = i.idx)][
res, on = .(id)][, `:=` (min_60 = NULL, plus_60 = NULL, idx = NULL)]

res2[]


   id minpricewithin60 index.minpricewithin60    PriorityDateTime TradePrice InstrumentSymbol            datetime
1:  1                3                      3 2018-10-27 10:00:00          1           asset1 2018-10-27 10:00:00
2:  2                4                      4 2018-10-27 10:00:30          2           asset2 2018-10-27 10:00:30
3:  3                1                      1 2018-10-27 10:01:00          3           asset1 2018-10-27 10:01:00
4:  4                2                      2 2018-10-27 10:01:30          4           asset2 2018-10-27 10:01:30
5:  5                3                      3 2018-10-27 10:02:00          5           asset1 2018-10-27 10:02:00
```

Comment: great, many thanks! Is there a particular reason why you used `which.min(i.idx)` instead of `which.min(i.TradePrice)` ? I checked and the result is identical.
Another question: after this chain `[res2,  on = .(InstrumentSymbol = InstrumentSymbol, datetime >= min_60, datetime <= plus_60), allow.cartesian = TRUE]` I am left with 3 columns somehow related to `datetime`: I have `datetime`, `datetime.1` and `i.datetime` could you please explain what they represent?

Comment: Actually, I think I've misread your instructions: in this case, it should be `.SD[which.min(abs(i.TradePrice - TradePrice))]`. I've corrected that, and now it should only return the closest trade price - in your example it didn't matter, because the differences between them were equal. Columns you mentioned are the result of a non-equi join on `datetime`. One column is for all the dates that were joined and satisfy the condition `>=`, another for all that are `<=`.

Comment: see this question for dplyr in case you'd like to try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53035534/r-dplyr-row-based-conditions-split-apply-combine

Comment: After check, this remains quite slow, just a bit faster than base R, are there any faster ways in `data.table`?

Comment: Not sure how fast is your `base R` solution, however this is more than 6x faster than the other solution posted here. I'm sure there is a better hack, keep the question open for some time, would be also interesting for me to see. Unfortunately, I doubt there will be a better solution in `dplyr` - I can think of `apply` functions, but doubt it's going to be fast.

Comment: actually it is much faster. with 180 000 rows my base solution takes 55 mins against 1.23 mins for yours, 44.7 times faster

Comment: another option using `by=.EACHI`, `iidx <- ndf[
        .(inst=InstrumentSymbol, prevMin=datetime-60L, nextMin=datetime+60L, idx=id, tp=TradePrice),

        .SD[id != idx, id[which.min(abs(TradePrice - tp))]],

        by=.EACHI,

        on=.(InstrumentSymbol=inst, datetime>=prevMin, datetime<=nextMin)];

    ndf[, c("minpricewithin60", "index.minpricewithin60") := .SD[iidx$V1, .(TradePrice, id)]]`

Comment: This question is now worth a bounty. @chinsoon, I have this error: `Error in `[.data.frame`(ndf, .(inst = InstrumentSymbol, prevMin = datetime -  : 
  unused arguments (by = .EACHI, on = .(InstrumentSymbol = inst, datetime >= prevMin, datetime <= nextMin))`

Comment: You need to run setDT(ndf）

Answer (score 2):

I have broken up the code to make a bit easier to see what is going on and troubleshoot. Really it is only the last line that takes any time at all. I also made the price data a bit more interesting and testable. It runs in ~ 1.3 min on my laptop.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1)
initial.date <- as.POSIXct('2018-10-27 10:00:00',tz='GMT')
last.date <- as.POSIXct('2018-12-28 17:00:00',tz='GMT') 
PriorityDateTime=seq.POSIXt(from=initial.date,to = last.date,by = '30 sec')
TradePrice=runif(length(PriorityDateTime))
ndf<- data.frame(PriorityDateTime,TradePrice)
ndf$InstrumentSymbol <- rep_len(x = c('asset1','asset2'),length.out = length(ndf$PriorityDateTime))
ndf$id <- seq(1:length(x = ndf$InstrumentSymbol))
ndf$datetime <- ymd_hms(ndf$PriorityDateTime)
setDT(ndf)

# Relevant Code

# Setup (Trivial Runtime):
ndf[, datetime_max := datetime + 60]
ndf[, datetime_min := datetime - 60]

ndf_x <- copy(ndf)
ndf_y <- copy(ndf)

names(ndf_x) <- paste0(names(ndf),"_x")
names(ndf_y) <- paste0(names(ndf),"_y")

ndf_join <- ndf_x[ndf_y,on = .(InstrumentSymbol_x = InstrumentSymbol_y, datetime_x >= datetime_min_y, datetime_x <= datetime_max_y), mult = "all", allow.cartesian = TRUE]
ndf_join <- ndf_join[id_x != id_y]

ndf_join[, price_delta := abs(TradePrice_y - TradePrice_x)]
```

This is the code that takes the most time:

```
# Harworking Runtime:
time_now <- Sys.time()
ndf_out <- ndf_join[,.SD[which.min(price_delta), .(which_price = id_x, what_price = TradePrice_x)], 
                      by = .(PriorityDateTime_y,TradePrice_y, id_y, InstrumentSymbol_x, datetime_y)]
cat(Sys.time() - time_now)
# 1.289397
```

Output:

```
ndf_out
         PriorityDateTime_y TradePrice_y   id_y InstrumentSymbol_x          datetime_y which_price what_price
     1: 2018-10-27 10:00:00   0.26550866      1             asset1 2018-10-27 10:00:00           3 0.57285336
     2: 2018-10-27 10:00:30   0.37212390      2             asset2 2018-10-27 10:00:30           4 0.90820779
     3: 2018-10-27 10:01:00   0.57285336      3             asset1 2018-10-27 10:01:00           1 0.26550866
     4: 2018-10-27 10:01:30   0.90820779      4             asset2 2018-10-27 10:01:30           6 0.89838968
     5: 2018-10-27 10:02:00   0.20168193      5             asset1 2018-10-27 10:02:00           3 0.57285336
    ---                                                                                                      
179397: 2018-12-28 16:58:00   0.54342007 179397             asset1 2018-12-28 16:58:00      179395 0.55391579
179398: 2018-12-28 16:58:30   0.25181676 179398             asset2 2018-12-28 16:58:30      179400 0.28088354
179399: 2018-12-28 16:59:00   0.08879969 179399             asset1 2018-12-28 16:59:00      179401 0.19670841
179400: 2018-12-28 16:59:30   0.28088354 179400             asset2 2018-12-28 16:59:30      179398 0.25181676
179401: 2018-12-28 17:00:00   0.19670841 179401             asset1 2018-12-28 17:00:00      179399 0.08879969
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, will familiarise myself with these types of joins

Answer (score 0):

Benchmarking the different solutions proposed so far (as a benchmark my base R approach took about 55 minutes with this data):

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(Chris(),
               chinsoon12.cpp(),
               arg0naut(),
               chinsoon12.data.table(), times=3L)
```

This was done with specs i5-6500T @ 2.50GHz and 8GB RAM.

[image: full benchmark]

```
> tm
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr         min          lq        mean     median          uq         max neval  cld
                 Chris() 95605.92838 95674.46039 96735.74794 95742.9924 97300.65772 98858.32305     3    d
        chinsoon12.cpp()    22.69009    23.07224    23.32106    23.4544    23.63655    23.81871     3 a   
              arg0naut() 84848.28652 85555.15312 86985.39963 86262.0197 88053.95619 89845.89267     3   c 
 chinsoon12.data.table() 66327.23992 66838.09245 67695.28538 67348.9450 68379.30811 69409.67124     3  b
```

I know that the question was related to `data.table` but considering that the Rcpp approach is 2886.251 times faster, I will award the bounty to this solution. Many thanks

Full code:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(data.table)
initial.date <- as.POSIXct('2018-10-27 10:00:00',tz='GMT')
last.date <- as.POSIXct('2018-12-28 17:00:00',tz='GMT') 
PriorityDateTime=seq.POSIXt(from=initial.date,to = last.date,by = '30 sec')
TradePrice=seq(from=1, to=length(PriorityDateTime),by = 1)
ndf<- data.frame(PriorityDateTime,TradePrice)
ndf$InstrumentSymbol <- rep_len(x = c('asset1','asset2'),length.out = length(ndf$PriorityDateTime))
ndf$id <- seq(1:length(x = ndf$InstrumentSymbol))
ndf$datetime <- ymd_hms(ndf$PriorityDateTime)
res <- ndf %>% data.table()
res2 <- res
setDT(ndf)
ndf2 <- ndf
chinsoon12.data.table <- function() {
  ndf[, rn:=.I]
  iidx <- ndf[
    .(inst=InstrumentSymbol, prevMin=datetime-60L, nextMin=datetime+60L, idx=id, tp=TradePrice),

    .SD[id != idx, rn[which.min(abs(TradePrice - tp))]],

    by=.EACHI,

    on=.(InstrumentSymbol=inst, datetime>=prevMin, datetime<=nextMin)];

  ndf[, c("minpricewithin60", "index.minpricewithin60") := .SD[iidx$V1, .(TradePrice, id)]]
}

arg0naut <- function() {
  res2[, `:=` (min_60 = datetime - 60, plus_60 = datetime + 60, idx = .I)][
    res2,  on = .(InstrumentSymbol = InstrumentSymbol, datetime >= min_60, datetime <= plus_60), allow.cartesian = TRUE][
      idx != i.idx, .SD[which.min(abs(i.TradePrice - TradePrice))], by = id][
        , .(id, minpricewithin60 = i.TradePrice, index.minpricewithin60 = i.idx)][
          res, on = .(id)][, `:=` (min_60 = NULL, plus_60 = NULL, idx = NULL)]
}

cppFunction('NumericVector nearestPrice(NumericVector id, NumericVector datetime, NumericVector price) {
            int i, j, n = id.size();
            NumericVector res(n);
            double prev, diff;

            for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            prev = 100000;

            j = i-1;
            while (datetime[j] >= datetime[i]-60 && j>=0) {
            diff = std::abs(price[i] - price[j]);

            if (diff < prev) {
            res[i] = id[j];
            prev = diff;
            }
            j--;
            }

            j = i+1;
            while (datetime[j] <= datetime[i]+60 && j<=n) {
            diff = std::abs(price[i] - price[j]);

            if (diff < prev) {
            res[i] = id[j];
            prev = diff;
            }
            j++;
            }
            }

            return(res);
            }')
chinsoon12.cpp <- function() {
  setorder(ndf2, InstrumentSymbol, PriorityDateTime)
  iidx <- ndf2[, nearestPrice(.I, datetime, TradePrice), by=.(InstrumentSymbol)]
  ndf2[, c("minpricewithin60", "index.minpricewithin60") := .SD[iidx$V1, .(TradePrice, id)]]
}




# Setup (Trivial Runtime):
Chris <- function() {
ndf[, datetime_max := datetime + 60]
ndf[, datetime_min := datetime - 60]
ndf_x <- copy(ndf)
ndf_y <- copy(ndf)
names(ndf_x) <- paste0(names(ndf),"_x")
names(ndf_y) <- paste0(names(ndf),"_y")
ndf_join <- ndf_x[ndf_y,on = .(InstrumentSymbol_x = InstrumentSymbol_y, datetime_x >= datetime_min_y, datetime_x <= datetime_max_y), mult = "all", allow.cartesian = TRUE]
ndf_join <- ndf_join[id_x != id_y]
ndf_join[, price_delta := abs(TradePrice_y - TradePrice_x)]
# Harworking Runtime:
time_now <- Sys.time()
ndf_out <- ndf_join[,.SD[which.min(price_delta), .(which_price = id_x, what_price = TradePrice_x)], 
                    by = .(PriorityDateTime_y,TradePrice_y, id_y, InstrumentSymbol_x, datetime_y)]
}




library(microbenchmark)
tm <- microbenchmark(Chris(),
               chinsoon12.cpp(),
               arg0naut(),
               chinsoon12.data.table(), times=3L)
ggplot2::autoplot(tm[c(2:4),])
```