# R: bind columns after lapply() the poly() function

Tags: r, lapply, poly

I want to add columns containing polynomials to a dataframe (DF).

Background: I need to use polynomials in a glmnet setting. I cannot call poly() directly in the glmnet() estimation command. I get an error, likely because my “Xtrain” data contain factors.
My workaround is to slice my Xtrain DF in two pieces, one containing all factors (for which no transformation is needed) and one containing the rest, viz. the numeric columns.

Now I want to add columns with polynomials to my numeric DF.
Here is a minimal example of my problem.

```
# Some data
x <- 1:10
y <- 11:20
df = as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

# Looks like this
    x  y
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 13

# Now I generate polys
lapply(df, function(i) poly(i, 2, raw=T)[,1:2])
```

However, I cannot figure out how to "cbind" the results. What I want to have in the end is a DF in which x, x^2, y, y^2, are contained. Order does not matter. However, ideally I would also have column labels (to identify the polys). For instance like this:

```
     x x2 y  y2
 1   1 1 11 121
 2   2 4 12 144
 3   3 9 13 169
```

Thank you...
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(i) poly(i, 2, raw=T)[,1:2]))
#   x.1 x.2 y.1 y.2
#1    1   1  11 121
#2    2   4  12 144
#3    3   9  13 169
# ...
```

As mentioned by @gpier and @akrun already, you might use `^` instead of `poly`

```
n <- 2
df[paste(names(df), n, sep = "_")] <- df^n
df
```

Comment: Thanks! This is so clean and easy and it also preserves the colnames...

Answer (score 2):

We can use `do.call`

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(df, function(i) poly(i, 2, raw=T)[,1:2]))
```

If we just need squares

```
cbind(df, as.matrix(df)^2)
```

Comment: akrun would you by chance have an answer for this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033225/r-data-table-row-based-conditions-split-apply-combine

Answer (score 2):

`poly` is not the right function if you need squares. Try

```
cbind(df,lapply(df, function(x) x^2))

    x  y   x   y
1   1 11   1 121
2   2 12   4 144
3   3 13   9 169
4   4 14  16 196
5   5 15  25 225
6   6 16  36 256
7   7 17  49 289
8   8 18  64 324
9   9 19  81 361
10 10 20 100 400
```

EDIT: indeed you don't even need `lapply`, you could just use `cbind(df, df^2)`

Comment: This can be simplified to `cbind(df, df^2)`.